# Umbraco, requests routed through the wrong RenderMvcController

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, umbraco

I have a problem with Umbraco. It might be that I lack some basic understanding of how Umbraco works.

#### Setup

1. a working Umbraco 7.2.8 installation
2. document types:   school and forums
3. structure: forums falls under school in the content tree.
4. a schoolcontroller which inherits from RenderMvcController
5. a forumscontroller which inherits from RenderMvcController as well.

#### Problem

When I try to access http://schoolproject.local:81/forums
the request is routed through the schoolcontroller instead of the forumscontroller. The correct view (forums) is still rendered though.
This happens for any controller I make, all requests are routed through the
schoolcontroller but the correct view is shown.

#### Tried solutions

Installed the project on a different server, tried making a new project with a clean Umbraco installation, cleared all temporary internet files. But I keep running into the same problem.

Any insight on how to fix this problem is appreciated.

Forumscontroller:

```
public class ForumsController : RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index (RenderModel model)
    {
        return  base.Index(model);
    }    
}
```

SchoolController:

```
public class SchoolController : RenderMvcController
{
    // GET: School
    public override ActionResult Index (RenderModel model)
    {
        return base.Index(model);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting,  this is the first time i post to stackoverflow :)

Comment: This sounds strange.. how do you know it goes through the SchoolController? In debug mode with breakpoint? And what Template is used on the Forum node in umbraco? (check it on the Properties tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the answer to this question. I didn't realize that Umbraco requires a content node for it's routing. I thought Umbraco would take an URL like localhost:81/forums and route it through the forumscontroller even if no content had been created.